# ASP.NET MVC Custom optional parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

How is it possible to define a route in ASP.NET MVC 5 that will ignore static prefixes/suffixes (like `"zip-"`, `"-county"`) for optional parameters if the latter not set?

So that in this case for example:

```
routes.Add("Search",
    new LowercaseDashedRoute(
    "search/{searchType}/{state}/{county}-county/{city}",
    new RouteValueDictionary(new {
        controller = "Home",
        action = "Search",            
        county = UrlParameter.Optional,
        city = UrlParameter.Optional }),
    new RouteValueDictionary(new { searchType = searchTypeConstraint }),
    new LowercaseDashedRouteHandler()));
```

when `county` is missing the URL would be like `/search/sale/ca/los-angeles` but **not** `/search/sale/ca/-county/los-angeles`

Answer (score 0):

You can set a constraint for your county parameter and then create another route without it:

```
routes.Add("Search",
    new LowercaseDashedRoute(
    "search/{searchType}/{state}/{county}/{city}",
    new RouteValueDictionary(new {
        controller = "Home",
        action = "Search",            
        county = UrlParameter.Optional,
        city = UrlParameter.Optional }),
    new RouteValueDictionary(new { searchType = searchTypeConstraint, county="\\S+-county" }),
    new LowercaseDashedRouteHandler()));
```

Route 2:

```
routes.Add("Search",
    new LowercaseDashedRoute(
    "search/{searchType}/{state}/{city}",
    new RouteValueDictionary(new {
        controller = "Home",
        action = "Search",
        city = UrlParameter.Optional }),
    new RouteValueDictionary(new { searchType = searchTypeConstraint }),
    new LowercaseDashedRouteHandler()));
```

The downside is that "-county" suffix will be added to the parameter, but you can easily handle this in your controller.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to have 2 optional parameters on a single route or to combine an optional parameter with a literal part in a segment.

However, to get the desired effect, you can just add another route to handle the case with no county (and remove the county as an optional parameter).

```
// Matches:
//     /search/sale/ca/los-angeles-county/los-angeles
//     /search/sale/ca/los-angeles-county
routes.Add("SearchCounty",
    new LowercaseDashedRoute(
    "search/{searchType}/{state}/{county}-county/{city}",
    new RouteValueDictionary(new {
        controller = "Home",
        action = "Search",            
        city = UrlParameter.Optional }),
    new RouteValueDictionary(new { searchType = searchTypeConstraint }),
    new LowercaseDashedRouteHandler()));

// Matches:
//     /search/sale/ca/los-angeles
routes.Add("Search",
    new LowercaseDashedRoute(
    "search/{searchType}/{state}/{city}",
    new RouteValueDictionary(new {
        controller = "Home",
        action = "Search" }),
    new RouteValueDictionary(new { searchType = searchTypeConstraint }),
    new LowercaseDashedRouteHandler()));
```

The routing engine will only match the first route if `<something>-county` is passed in as the 4th segment, so it will be able to distinguish that case from just passing a `city` argument.